# How to style gatsby-image with css or non-inline styles

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am using gatsby and inside of gatsby I am using gatsby-image. I want to do some media queries on it so I need to use some css or non react inline styling. I know you can do something like this normally

```
 <Img sizes={this.props.data.img.sizes} style={{height: '30px'}} className="imageOfMine" />
```

but I need media queries so I need a way to use some styled-jsx or css. I tried referencing the className inside styled-jsx, but that did not work either.

Comment: I found a work-around using styled-components, but I'm going to wait to see if someone has a better answer.